# how to display only 10 secs of data in a graph? Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, axis

I am working on an experiment where I take temperature readings and graph the result in real-time on a temperature vs time graph. The code i am currently using graphs the whole 90 secs worth of data on the figure. I am trying to display only 10 secs worth of data on the figure so I can analyze the data better. For example, for the first 10 secs all the already taken data to show at the 11th sec it will show the data from 1-11 secs and after that it will show the data 2-12 secs and so on. I have tried to change the axes settings on the graph but its not working well.
here's the code i am using

```
a=arduino('COM5');% connect to ardunino
ai_pin= 0;
tic;
i=0;

while toc<90;
    i=i+1;
    time(i)=toc; 
    toc_show=time(i)+10;  
    t(i)=a.analogRead(ai_pin); %temperature reading
    figure(1);
    plot(time,v);
    axis([time(i),toc_show,0,500]);% should set axis to display needed data but doesn't work well
    pause(0.01);
    currFrame = getframe(gcf);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the x-axis to display the *next* 10 seconds, not previous.

You could use this instead:

```
xmin = time(i) - 10;
xmax = time(i);
axis([xmin,xmax,0,500]);
```

Or to fix the limits to [0 10] for the first 10 seconds:

```
xmin = max(time(i) - 10, 0);
xmax = max(time(i), 10);
```